# How should I go about returning a struct variable that is populated by a function in C?

Tags: c, struct

I am looking to manipulate the frames of a struct within a function, so I may assign the struct data which is returned from the function to a variable within my main() program.
(I hope this makes sense)
I will provide some example code which hopefully explains what I am trying to do.

I have defined my struct in a .h file, written my function in a .c file, and I am hoping to be able to assign within my main() .c file.

```
//code from .h file
#include <stdint.h>

typedef union {
    struct {
        uint8_t x;
        uint8_t y;
        uint8_t z;
    } frame;
} testing;
```

```
//function code from .c file
#include "struct_test.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

testing assign(void){
    static testing value;
    uint8_t ex1 = 0x00;
    uint8_t ex2 = 0x01;
    uint8_t ex3 = 0x02;
    
    ex1 |= 1UL << 0;
    ex1 |= 1UL << 2;
    
    value.frame.x = ex1;
    value.frame.y = ex2 + ex3;
    value.frame.z = ex3 - ex2;
    
    return value;   
}
```

```
// main() .c file
#include "struct_test.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    testing test1;

    while (1) {
        test1 = assign();
    }
}
```

the contents of assign() is not really important, I am just trying to do some arbitrary stuff with the struct frames so I can verify the function is working correctly while I step through the program in debug mode, and then move towards getting the function to do some useful things.

I keep running into compile errors which refer to "incompatible data types".

I have read online that these problems are generally to do with pointers and memory addresses, however I find all of the explanations quite confusing when it is relative to other peoples programs. I would really really appreciate if somebody could give advice that is related to my code.

Kind regards =D

Comment: Try adding `testing assign(void);` to the .h file.

Comment: Rather than only _describe_ the error with "compile errors which refer to "incompatible data types".", post the exact error message.

Comment: Try stricter warnings and reading them.

Comment: You need to declare `testing assign(void);` somewhere, possibly in the `"//code from .h file"` header file

Comment: How does a union with a single member make any sense?

Comment: As for your compiler errors, it sounds like you are using an obsolete non-standard compiler. I'd recommend using gcc and then follow the recommendations from [What compiler options are recommended for beginners learning C?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/282565)

Answer (score 2):

A C program is divided into compilation units that are compiled independly. Your program has 2 such compilation units, namely the `struct_test.c` and the `main.c` files. If a function from one compiliation unit is to be called from the other, it must know the types of the arguments and the result type. To show this information to all compilation units involved, you typically define a function prototype in a header file and include it in all compilation units, that use or define the function.

In your case you did define the function `assign` in `struct_test.c` but you did not put a function prototype in the header. Therefore if compiling the `main.c` file, the compiler does know nothing about the function `assign` and throws an error. You should provide a function prototype in your header file after the `typedef` declaration of the testing struct:

```
testing assign(void);
```

Note that the error message may be misleading if you use an old compiler (or even a recent compiler without explicitly stating the C standard version). This is due to the fact, that in old C versions, you could call a function without providing a prototype. In such a case the compiler implicitly assumes an `int` return value. This is the reason why you probably got some error like the following. (gcc 9.3.0 on ubuntu)

```
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:9:17: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘assign’[-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    9 |         test1 = assign();
      |                 ^~~~~~
main.c:9:17: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘testing’ {aka ‘union <anonymous>’} from type ‘int’
```

So the compiler first gives a warning, that the function was implicitly declared (which is because you did not provide a prototype in the header). And then it throws an error, becaus it cannot match the `int` return type from that implicitly declared function with your `test1` struct.

I do not know if you also got the warning in your case, but you should really enable warnings in your compiler, as C is a language with many historical syntax and language features, that are often dangerous to use.